Orientation covering
My question is about whether or not the image of an open set is still an open set. I'm going to write the construction of the orientation covering and then I'll ask what I can't figure out.
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with $\dim M=n$ and consider $E:=\bigwedge^nT^*M$ its vector bundle whose elements are pairs $(p,\omega_p)$ where $$\omega_p:T_pM\times\dots\times T_pM\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is a $n$-multilinear alternating map. We always have $proj:E\to M\quad (p,\omega_p)\mapsto p$ the projection, and the zero section given by $s_0:M\to E\quad p\mapsto(p,0_p)$ where $0_p$ is the zero map from $T_pM\times\dots\times T_pM$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Since $s_0(M)$ is closed in $E$ we have that $E\setminus s_0(M)$ is itself a smooth manifold. We have removed all zero maps, so we can quotient $E\setminus s_0(M)$ by the action of the group$(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\cdot)$ which means that $$(p,\omega_p)\sim(q,\eta_q)\iff\cases{p=q \\ \omega_p=\lambda\cdot \eta_p\quad\ for\ some\ \lambda >0}\quad $$ We then have a surjective map $q:E\setminus s_0(M)\to\tilde{M}\quad (p,\omega_p)\mapsto (p,[\omega_p])$ where $\tilde{M}:=\frac{E\setminus s_0(M)}{\sim}$. By putting the quotient topology on $\tilde{M}$ we make $q$ continuous, open and we have a well defined, surjective, continuous function $$\pi:\tilde{M}\to M\quad (p,[\omega_p])\mapsto p$$ Such that $proj=\pi\circ q$. This map $\pi$ is indeed the orientation covering of $M$. We need to show that it is a double topological covering, and being $M$ smooth, we will have $\pi$ a smooth covering.
Take $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ a chart with $x_\alpha^1,\dots,x_{\alpha}^n$ coordinate function. This chart is locally oriented by the (local) volume form $$\omega_\alpha=dx_{\alpha}^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{\alpha}^n$$ We can define two sections $$s_{\alpha}^\pm:U_{\alpha}\to E\setminus s_0(M)\quad p\mapsto (p,\pm\omega_{\alpha,p})$$ The image is in $E\setminus s_0(M)$ because $\omega_\alpha$ is a volume form. We then define $U_{\alpha}^\pm:=q\circ s_{\alpha}^\pm(U_{\alpha})$ and it is true that $$\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)=U_{\alpha}^+\sqcup U_{\alpha}^-\quad \pi_{|U_{\alpha}^\pm}:U_{\alpha}^\pm\to U_{\alpha}\ homeomorphism$$ So this is a double smooth covering of $M$.
My question is: why are $U_{\alpha}^\pm$ open? More precisely, I would like to understand why $s_{\alpha}^{\pm}(U_{\alpha})$ are open subsets of $E\setminus s_0(M)$ , because since $q$ is open if I want to show $U_{\alpha}^\pm$ to be open I need to show first that $s_{\alpha}^\pm(U_\alpha)$ are open as well.
Thanks in advance to everyone willing to help me!

Do you know that a diffeomorphism sends open sets to open sets?

Yes I do. But $s_{\alpha}^\pm$ is not a diffeomorphism as it is not surjective. Maybe it is a diffeomorphism onto its image, so $s_{\alpha}^\pm(U_{\alpha})$ is open in itself, but I still need to prove that this is open in $E\setminus s_0(M)$. Am I missing something?

Since $\pi \circ s^\pm_\alpha = id$, we know that $s^\pm_\alpha$ has rank $n$ all points of $U_\alpha$, i.e. is an immersion. Moreover it is a homeomorphism onto its image and therefore a smooth embedding. Thus $U^\pm_\alpha$ is a smooth submanifold of $\tilde M$ which has the same dimension as $\tilde M$. This means that it is open in $\tilde M$.
